# How to get the date/time in a specific timezone?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I've been using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) to work with date/times in javascript.  My goal is to determine what time it is in PST regardless of where a user is.  I had been using this method:

```
var pstTime = moment().utc().subtract('hours', 7);
```

Which worked up until daylight savings time a few weeks back.  Now it is one hour off and causing some problems.  Is there a way (either in moment.js or standard JS) to just pull the time for a specific time zone?

Comment: Daylight savings time is for the summer months, the winter months use standard times. UTC is a standard time. PST is a standard time. It looks like you were using PDT during the daylight savings.

Comment: Hrrm, so for California it's on PDT during daylight savings and PST the rest of the time?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Moment timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).

```
var pstTime = moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I'd argue that the essential part of the answer is to use the library / extension, and the link is for convenience. Either way, I've edited to add a solution using the linked library.